# Cannot synchronize two nodes in private Ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, synchronization

I am trying to build a private testnet with two nodes. 
This is my genesis block:

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block":0,
    "eip158Block":0
    },
    "difficulty":"0x400",
    "gasLimit": "0x2100000",
    "alloc": {
        "ba1464c6a4afb32f6b3eb6d750248d27e2c9925a":
        { "balance":"0x1337000000000000000000"}
    }
}
```

I have started by initializing a single node with this command:

```
./geth --identity "1"  --datadir /home/davide/Documents/Ether/ --networkid 4999 --rpc --rpcport 40901 --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --port 30303 --nodiscover --ipcpath /home/davide/Documents/Ether/geth.ipc
```

Then I attached a console to it with the command:

```
./geth attach /home/davide/Documents/Ether/geth.ipc
```

and I made some transactions and mined 630 blocks.

Now I want to add a new node to my private blockchain and make it synchronize with the other nodes. 
I initialized a new node with this command:

```
./geth --identity "2"  --datadir /home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/ --networkid 4999 --rpc --rpcport 40900 --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --port 30300 --nodiscover --ipcpath /home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/geth.ipc init /home/davide/Documents/Ether/a.json
```

The `a.json` is the genesis block which is the same used for the other node as well

Then I launched it with:

```
./geth --identity "2"  --datadir /home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/ --networkid 4999 --rpc --rpcport 40900 --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --port 30300 --nodiscover --ipcpath /home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/geth.ipc
```

and I attached a console with the command:

```
./geth attach /home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/geth.ipc
```

So now I have the first node with 600 blocks and the second node with 0 blocks. To connect the two nodes I executed in the second node the command:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://9968520a028521084cb904b4c19ff9a40277c9f22f83b3bc2d3be944497ed55e5a0a1782c6f3d6e6b879ec3f806eb735670a7184c2026b438250fdff3e98c588@172.17.0.1:30303?discport=0")
```

where enode is the identity of the first node and 172.17.0.1 is the local IP address. The nodes are running on the same linux virtual machine.

The I get the following output:

```
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/2/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/geth/chaindata cache=768 handles=512
WARN [03-27|16:24:27] Upgrading database to use lookup entries 
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 15 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: <nil> Constantinople: <nil> Engine: unknown}"
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/davide/.ethash                         count=2
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=4999
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Database deduplication successful        deduped=0
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=36a78b…0fbdc8 td=1024
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=36a78b…0fbdc8 td=1024
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=36a78b…0fbdc8 td=1024
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] RLPx listener up                         self="enode://4ae8ab68997bca30e5c91495d9610ddbe3cd49082447710b0754b3b91880fa2946fa2fa8a24bcbc512356d51343ee38fb490594fa7645395f20d5c35d8144bde@[::]:30300?discport=0"
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://127.0.0.1:40900 cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [03-27|16:24:27] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/davide/Documents/Ether/2nd/geth.ipc
INFO [03-27|16:24:31] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x494a61d7c8C48Bb47C59261e3F7C46f6B5D102d5
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Block synchronisation started 
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new state entries               count=426 elapsed=869.471µs processed=426 pending=62 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new state entries               count=22  elapsed=137.697µs processed=448 pending=0  retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=20.183ms  number=192 hash=15b72f…071529 ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block receipts              count=27  elapsed=3.143ms   number=27  hash=82726c…b0614c size=56.94kB ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block receipts              count=165 elapsed=12.946ms  number=192 hash=15b72f…071529 size=70.97kB ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=35.971ms  number=384 hash=1dd324…af81c0 ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block receipts              count=2   elapsed=105.541µs number=194 hash=2c4cec…04979f size=8.00B   ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block receipts              count=190 elapsed=22.647ms  number=384 hash=1dd324…af81c0 size=71.95kB ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=179.280ms number=576 hash=9176d3…d96d9c ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block receipts              count=7   elapsed=1.957ms   number=391 hash=8a915b…59c18f size=28.00B  ignored=0
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block receipts              count=174 elapsed=9.873ms   number=565 hash=0dbc2a…886588 size=91.09kB ignored=0
WARN [03-27|16:25:37] Node data write error                    err="state node 9e37b1…5c7c0a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
INFO [03-27|16:25:37] Imported new block headers               count=54  elapsed=67.773ms  number=630 hash=962920…003b4c ignored=0
WARN [03-27|16:25:37] Rolled back headers                      count=630 header=630->0 fast=565->0 block=0->0
WARN [03-27|16:25:37] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 9e37b1…5c7c0a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=5.381ms   number=192 hash=15b72f…071529 ignored=192
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=5.386ms   number=384 hash=1dd324…af81c0 ignored=192
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block receipts              count=0   elapsed=56.831µs  number=27  hash=82726c…b0614c size=0.00B   ignored=27
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block receipts              count=0   elapsed=216.716µs number=192 hash=15b72f…071529 size=0.00B   ignored=165
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block receipts              count=0   elapsed=27.26µs   number=194 hash=2c4cec…04979f size=0.00B   ignored=2
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=5.145ms   number=576 hash=9176d3…d96d9c ignored=192
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=2.148ms   number=630 hash=962920…003b4c ignored=54
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block receipts              count=0   elapsed=720.4µs   number=384 hash=1dd324…af81c0 size=0.00B   ignored=190
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block receipts              count=0   elapsed=107.955µs number=391 hash=8a915b…59c18f size=0.00B   ignored=7
INFO [03-27|16:25:47] Imported new block receipts              count=0   elapsed=608.307µs number=565 hash=0dbc2a…886588 size=0.00B   ignored=174
WARN [03-27|16:25:47] Node data write error                    err="state node 9e37b1…5c7c0a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-27|16:25:47] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 9e37b1…5c7c0a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
```

What is the problem in my setup? Why aren't the nodes syncing?

Comment: is the field `Hash` from the output of eth.getBlock(0) the same on both nodes?

Comment: add the output  of `admin.peers` for both of your nodes to the question

Comment: you are using wrong `--networkid` parameter, it should be 15 in your case

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this exact problem for me was adding node #1's enode to node #2's `<datadir>/geth/static-nodes.json` file, as described in [the documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes). That's a way to persistently add a peer node, and it fixed my sync issue--I'm not completely sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same procedure as you did. Made sure I have atleast 3 total nodes. The block counts on the second node stayed at 0. What i was missing was a transaction. **I sent a transfer of ether between 2 accounts and started mining on the first node**, and voila! The sync issue stopped